# How to unittest Django Rest Framework endpoint with XML?

Tags: python, django, xml, django-rest-framework

I've got an endpoint which I built with Django Rest Framework. It works great when I test it with something like Postman, but my unit tests fail.

When I test my JSON endpoints I always post Python dicts instead of JSON strings, like this:

```
response = self.client.post('/json-endpoint/', {'a': 1}, format='json')
```

When I test the XML endpoint I tried to post a raw xml string like this:

```
response = self.client.post('/xml-endpoint/', '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><myDataStructure></myDataStructure>', format='xml')
```

But this doesn't work. In my Viewset I override the `create()` method, and in there, my XML somehow seems to be "packaged" into another XML. If I print out `request.body` in the create() method I see this:

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<root>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?&gt;\n&lt;myDataStructure&gt;\n etc..
```

As you can see my XML is somehow encoded and then packed into another `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<root>`.

How can I properly provide the XML when I write unit tests for the XML endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In unit tests I use this:

```
result = self.client.post(
    path='/xml-endpoint/', 
    data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><myDataStructure></myDataStructure>', 
    content_type='text/xml',
)
```